# Angular routing back without redrawing UI

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

I am routing from a grid to an edit page. What I am wanting to happen is when I hit the back button, instead of redrawing the grid, I'd like for it to just go back to the page exactly as it was before. Is there a setting or a way for me to accomplish this in my routing?

I've thought about putting everything i need in the URL, but that would be a huge URL which is out unfortunately. Plus, I don't need to get the initialized data again.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<a class="btn btn-danger" href="javascript:history.back()">Go Back</a>`

Comment: If `exactly as it was before` means that it should have the same data, without reloading itself, then one way would be to create a custom `RouteReuseStrategy`. It would be easier to exemplify if you could create a StackBlitz demo or something like that.